# Why only works the first video call on Android SDK QuickBlox?

Tags: java, android, video, call, quickblox

I'm developing an Android app that include a service of video chat (using the QuickBlox's SDK). All is fine on the first received call, but after of hang up the video call, the device can't received more calls.

The only suspicious message error is:

`E/class com.xxxx.xxxx.services.CallService: Ping chat server failed`

Also webrtc.Logging detect the second and more incoming calls, but not show the incoming call fragment.

I'm using QuickBlox SDK version 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you reproduce this issue on [QuickBlox's Video Call Sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc)? Maybe in callback onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession session) you check for current session not null and hungs up call because you not cleaned first session on callback onSessionClosed(QBRTCSession session).

Comment: Effectively the session never was closed, and this happens because I put the call of `activity.finish()` method before to close the video call current session. To solve the problem I moved the call to `finish()` to the last line of the method `hangUpCurrentSession()`.